# Can't find Google place id

Tags: google-my-business-api

I want to find a place id for a business, but it is not showing up when I type it into Google's place id lookup:
https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

The business name is in Hebrew: טוביה לרנר טוען רבני ומגשר
It is verified and is NOT a service area business.

Why isn't it showing up? By the way, do I need some sort of Google+ presence?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a long time to find the place id for my clients business. All of the suggested tools were giving weird results.

This tool ended up working for me: https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772#place_id